# Switching to Xbox One from Xbox 360

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-v, xbox-one

If I have moddered money on GTA V online Xbox 360 and I switch to the Xbox One, will I lose all of it and all the stuff I've spent it on as well?
This includes cars, Pegasus vehicles, guns and property. If someone could tell me that would be great.

Comment: Please don't ask for users to respond via email. If you post a question on this site, users will answer in the section below. Also, please try to use punctuation and grammar (Capital letters!) to the best of your ability.

Comment: Do you mean you have a character on one and 360? You can transfer your character to one, but you would continue playing off your 360 character

Comment: Nar im getting a one and would like to no if the money ive gotten moddered to me will get taken away when i play gta v on it. Timelord64

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so as long as you keep the same Gamer-tag and XBL account. Just to be safe, I would suggest going to this site:
https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/202892778-Transferring-Your-Previous-Grand-Theft-Auto-Online-Characters-and-Progression-to-PlayStation-4-Xbox-One-or-PC
It explains a lot.

Comment: You may want to add the relevant information from that link in case the link goes down. That way, your answer is still useful.